# Generate the same key at every execution

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm now starting to deal with some security measures for my application.
Is there a way of generating a key that is "attached" to the specific application, so that in each different execution of the program the application generates the same key?
I'm using VB.NET.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: a `GUID` comes to mind, but I am confused about first 'attaching' and then later 'generating'.  See also: **Project Properties -> Application -> Assembly Information** there is already one attached

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. A constant string is a key that would be same on every execution, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, the way your question is phrased, you're just looking for a string variable. Maybe perhaps you want a string that is different for each machine or user? Who knows.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't manage to explain the situation properly. If I use a simple static string then, using a decompiling program, the key can be easily obtained, making the cyphered version of my data easy to be read. So my idea was to generate the key runtime when needed, so that the key is not phisically stored anywhere. Is it so bad approach? Thank you!